# search mac addresses connected to windows mobile hotspot

Tags: windows, terminal, mac-address, arp, hotspot

I would like to list all mac addresses connected to my mobile hotspot in windows at that instance. I know "arp -a" command can be used to list all the addresses but it does not update the list when any device disconnects from the hotspot. Is there any way I can get updated mac address list through the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way of getting updated list of active host MAC addresses I can think of is to scan network and collect updated data on demand.

[Nmap](https://nmap.org/) is a great tool for this stuff, all you need is to run arp scan with `nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -sn -v` (replace network address with yours)